# Registering a custom component in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'd like to use the [ic-tabs](https://github.com/instructure/ic-tabs) component in my Ember CLI app. It turns out ic-tabs doesn't export with the naming that auto resolves in Ember CLI (so I can't just use {{ic-tabs}} in my app).

How would I go about using an initializer to register the components within my app?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with the introduction of [ember-cli-addons](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/06/24/introducing_ember_cli_addons.html)

One of the key features what ember-cli-addons (ECA) does is:

> Providing a custom application tree to be merged with the consuming application. This allows  you to distribute anything that might need to be imported in the consuming application;  including components, templates, routes, mixins, helpers, etc.

So it's necesary to re-write the ic-*whatever-component to an ember-cli app and then import as addon. This would solve he *import* problem once for all developers, compared to an approach where everybody had to rewrite the ic-* to fit his app.

And did u check this mechanism used in ember-cli -> [ember-load-initializers](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers)